# detecting anomaly from cdr data

Tags: machine-learning, r, dataset, data-science-model, ipython

[image: This is my sample dataset]

I need to find anomalies from this. The term anomaly in my case is in which square id and in which time the total activity goes higher, how can I detect anomalies with the help of machine learning algorithms.

Comment: How about you standardize your activity variable and look for extreme values?

Comment: that activity_time is from 00 to 23(24 hours of one day(2013-12-01))

Comment: It is still unclear what those data represent and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i completed this project and published my paper